# How to implement this remove function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a remove button that removes all that is between the li tag whose the button is inside.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#Adicionar1').click(function() {
        $('#list1').append("<li>"+ $("#Texto1").val() +"<button>remover</button>" +"</li>");
$("#Texto1").val("");        
    });

    $('button').click(function() {


    });


});
```

code:
http://jsfiddle.net/bdMAF/917/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you can not add an event to an element that does not exist. You need to either attach the event when the button is added or use event delegation.

```
$('#list1').on("click", "li button", function() {  //listen for click on button
    $(this)  //the button that was clicked
        .closest("li")  //find the li element
        .remove();      //remove the li
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use jQuery's `.parent()` function, and make use of `data` attributes:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.Adicionar').click(function() {
        console.log($(this).data("listid"));
        console.log($(this).data("textid"));
        
        $("#"+$(this).data("listid")).append("<li>"+         $("#"+$(this).data("textid")).val() +'<button class="remove">remover</button>' +"</li>");
        
    $("#"+$(this).data("textid")).val("");    
        $('.remove').on("click",function() {       
            $(this).parent().remove();
        });
    });



});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>TEMAS A APRENDER</h3>
<input id= "Texto1" type="text" name="" value="">
    <button class="Adicionar" data-listid="list1" data-textid="Texto1">Adicionar</button>
<ul id="list1"></ul>

<h3>TEMAS APRENDIDOS</h3>
<input id= "Texto2" type="text" name="" value="">
    <button class="Adicionar" data-listid="list2" data-textid="Texto2">Adicionar</button>
<ul id="list2"></ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar answer to one above: http://jsfiddle.net/bdMAF/920/

HTML

```
<span class="delegateAnchor">
    <h3>TEMAS A APRENDER</h3>

    <input id="Texto1" type="text" name="" value="">
    <button id="Adicionar1">Adicionar</button>
    <ul id="list1"></ul>

    <h3>TEMAS APRENDIDOS</h3>

    <input id="Texto2" type="text" name="" value="">
    <button id="Adicionar2">Adicionar</button>
    <ul id="list2"></ul>
</span>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $list1 = $('#list1');
    var $text1 = $("#Texto1");

    $('#Adicionar1').click(function () {
        var $li = $('<li>');
        $li.append($text1.val()).append("<button>remover</button>");
        $list1.append($li);
        $text1.val('');
    });

    $('.delegateAnchor > ul').on('click', 'button', function() {
        $(this).parent().remove();
    });
});
```